# R script using consecutive rows with allowance frame

Tags: r

I am trying to create an R script that says, "make a new variable and, based on a previous variable 'scores,' put a 1 for ten consecutive 'scores' in which at least 8 of those 10 'scores' are at or above 1952"

Comment: An example data set and the desired result with what you have tried will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about this with `zoo::rollapply()`

```
#make dataframe with scores
df<-data.frame(score=sample(1000:3000,2000))

require(zoo) # for rollapply() function
df$newvar<-c(rep(0,9),rollapply(df,width=10,FUN=function(x)ifelse(length(x[x>=1952])>=8,1,0)))
head(df[df$newvar==1,])

    score newvar
25   2695      1
26   2750      1
30   2468      1
140  2525      1
141  2515      1
275  1989      1
```